# The set $F$ of all functions $f:\Bbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$ that are "eventually zero" is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Prove or disprove the set $F$ of all functions $f:\Bbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$ that are ''eventually zero'' is countable.**

For each $n\in \Bbb{N}$, let $F_n = \{f: \Bbb{N}\to\{0, 1\}:f(i) = 0 \forall i > n\}$. Then it is easy to see that $F_n$ is finite.
How to prove rigorously?

function $f$ is eventually zero means $f(n)=0$ $\forall$ $n\geq N$, $N\in \Bbb{N}$.

Define  a map $\psi: \Bbb{N} \to \{0,1\}^\Bbb{N}$ such that
$\psi(i)=\{f(i):i\in\{0,2,...,n-1\}$
$\psi(i)=\{0:i\notin\{0,2,...,n-1\}$.

Does this map work?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by “does this map work”?

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho I want to prove that set of all functions $F$ is countable. Does the map $\psi$ is bijective?

Comment: $\{0, 1\}^n$ is a finite set, there is no way $\psi$ can be bijective.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho How to prove $F$ is countable rigorously?

Comment: I have written an answer which shows why $F$ is countable. i must add that @rschwieb has an answer below that constructs a beautiful and simple bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $F$ which is more in your spirit if you were looking for an explicit bijection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal was to establish a bijection between the set of maps and a countable set, but you proposed a map from $\mathbb N \rightarrow \{0,1\}^\mathbb N$.  The second one is uncountable, so it’s unclear how that’s going to help.

Anyhow, the thing that occurs to me first is to consider this following. Enumerate the prime numbers in $\mathbb N$ as $p_0,p_1,p_2,\ldots$ and so on.  Then consider the map $\theta$ that takes $\theta(f)=\prod_{i=0}^\infty p_i^{f(i)}$. This is well defined since the sequences are eventually $0$.  Show $\theta$ is an injection of that set of functions into the positive integers.

In fact, the larger set of functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ which are eventually zero is bijective with the positive integers using this map. (This is just the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.)

By only considering the functions into $\{0,1\}$ you are obtaining the restriction of the map and its image is onto the squarefree positive integers.

Comment: What is your domain and codomain here?

Comment: @Unknown The set of functions you described and the positive integers, respectively. It’s right there.

Comment: How it came to in mind that we should choose this type of function ? The way it is defined is looking beautiful but how to  think in this way?

Comment: Sorry, I managed to forget that we were only talking about finitely supported functions into $\{0,1\}$ and not into $\mathbb N$. I corrected the conclusion.  What I had previously written showed a bijection with the finitely supported functions from $\mathbb N$ into $\mathbb N$ are countable.

Comment: @Unknown It came to mind because of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: As for as I am getting, $\theta: \{0,1\}^\infty \to \Bbb{N}$ such that $\theta(f)=\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{f(i)}$. I can see that $\theta$ is injective. Thus set of all functions $F$ is countable. Am i right?

Comment: @Unknown No, if $H=\{f:\mathbb N\to \{0,1\}\mid \text{ f eventually zero }\}$, then $\theta:H\to \mathbb N$.  You seem to be overlooking a layer of what is going on.

Comment: Sorry, You are right. I got it completely. Thanks for bearing me(+1).

Answer (score 3):

Just writing numbers from $\mathbb{N}$ in binary effectively identifies every number in $\mathbb{N}$ with a function of the form you describe. Conversely every such function is basically telling you how to write down a binary number, from right to left.

For example, suppose $$\begin{align}f:{}&1\to0\\&2\to1\\&3\to0\\&4\to0\\&5\to1\end{align}$$ and all else to $0$. This identifies with the binary integer $$\stackrel{5}{1}\stackrel{4}{0}\stackrel{3}{0}\stackrel{2}{1}\stackrel{1}{0}$$ which is $18$ in binary. So this $f\leftrightarrow 18$.

And for example, start with the number $23$, which is $10111$. This defines $$\begin{align}g:{}&1\to1\\&2\to1\\&3\to1\\&4\to0\\&5\to1\end{align}$$ So $g\leftrightarrow23$.

More formally, there is a map $\varphi:\mathbb{N}\to F$, such that if $n$ is $b_kb_{k-1}\cdots b_1$ in binary, then $\left(\varphi(n)\right)(m)=b_m$, where $b_m=0$ for $m>k$.

And there is $\varphi^{-1}:F\to \mathbb{N}$ where $\varphi^{-1}(f)=f(k)\cdots f(2)f(1)$ (read as a binary concatenation) where $k$ is the largest number for which $f$ returns $1$.

So there is a very direct enumeration of these functions, which makes them countable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that If $f:\mathbb{N}\to \{0, 1\}$ is eventually zero, it means that there is some $M$ such that $f(i)=0$ for all $i>M.$ Therefore, $$\{f| f:\mathbb{N}\to \{0, 1\}, f \text{is eventually zero}\}\subseteq \bigcup_{M\in \mathbb{N}} \{f: f(i)=0 \hspace{2mm} \forall i>M\}=:\mathcal{F}_M.$$

It is now clear that it suffices to show that for each $M\in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $\{f: f(i)=0 \hspace{2mm} \forall i>M\}$ is at most countable. But it is easily seen that $|\mathcal{F}_M|\le 2^M.$

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote by $\{0,1\}^\infty$ to the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$ that are *eventually zero*.

Then, for $f \in \{0,1\}^\infty$ let $n_f := \min\{N \in \mathbb N : \forall n \geq N (f(n) = 0)\}$ and consider the map
\begin{align}
\{0,1\}^\infty & \to \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \{0,1\}^n \\[1mm]
f & \mapsto (f(1),\dots,f(n_f)) \in \{0,1\}^{n_f}
\end{align}
with the convention that $\{0,1\}^0 = \{0\}$.

Comment: It really bounced over my head. How,$\{0,1\}^\infty$ be the set of all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$ that are *eventually zero*. also i didn't get  the construction of the next set.